# XAML Fit Image to Page Size Inside ScrollViewer

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime

I have an `Image` inside a `ScrollViewer`. Some of the images are too large to fit inside the `Page`. How can I have the `Image` be sized down to the `Page` size when first shown?

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Image Stretch="None" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Updated Answer**

This is what I did instead based on Filip's answer here, and another he answered to a similar question  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058018/zoom-out-image-to-fit-scrollviewer-dimensions)

XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer">
    <Image x:Name="image" Stretch="None" SizeChanged="ImageSizeChanged" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code Behind:

```
private bool imageSizeSet;
private void ImageSizeChanged( object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e )
{
    if( imageSizeSet || !( image.ActualWidth > scrollViewer.ViewportWidth ) && !( image.ActualHeight > scrollViewer.ViewportHeight ) )
    {
        return;
    }

    // If the image is larger than the screen, zoom it out.
    var zoomFactor = (float)Math.Min( scrollViewer.ViewportWidth / image.ActualWidth, scrollViewer.ViewportHeight / image.ActualHeight );
    scrollViewer.ZoomToFactor( zoomFactor );
    imageSizeSet = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<ScrollViewer
    x:Name="theScrollViewer"
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    SizeChanged="OnSizeChanged">
    <Image
        x:Name="theImage"
        Stretch="Uniform" />
</ScrollViewer>

private void OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    theImage.Width = theScrollViewer.ViewportWidth;
    theImage.Height = theScrollViewer.ViewportHeight;
}
```

Comment: This is chopping off some of the image. What I would like is for the whole image to show, but zoomed out enough where I can see the whole image when the page initially loads, so the user doesn't have to zoom out.

Comment: Well then also set the sizes when the image loads and perhaps add `theScrollViewer.ZoomToFactor(1);` before those. I haven't seen anything chopped off. Are you sure you set `Stretch` to `Uniform`?

Comment: If forgot `Stretch=Uniform`. It works now. One odd thing though. When I zoom in and out, the image isn't centered. In the example I gave the image always stays centered. Is there a way to have it be centered still?

Comment: I guess you could disable `HorizontalScrollMode` and `VerticalScrollMode`, but do you really want to disable panning?

Comment: It's fine if the image is larger than the screen. If it's smaller, it's not centered and I can't pan anyways. That's the issue. When you zoom way out and the image is small, it's not centered, and you can't pan.

Comment: Not sure how to address that, but that's a different question anyway. You could set `theScrollViewer.MinZoomFactor = 1;` if that would work for you.

Comment: That seems to behave well. Thanks Filip!

Comment: Filip: I ended up doing something slightly different which I put as an update to the question. It now behaves exactly as I want it. Thanks for all your help.